# Am working on webhooks, am new to Salesforce and I do not have knowledge on SF dev or Apex, can someone help with Webhooks with SF flow?

Tags: webhooks

How to send data to webhook using salesforce flow? without using any outbound message or any apex class?
Can you please assist me or share any examples if you have?

Comment: What have you tried? The documentation is here for doing a callout from a flow: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_http_callout.htm&type=5

I suspect there's probably some Trailhead content around it too, which will likely be easier to follow, but if you want to get a good answer here then showing what you've tried and where you're stuck will make that more likely to happen!